# Testing window.body.scrollTop in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

How can I test the `window.body.scrollTop` value using Protractor?

I am trying:

```
expect(
    element(window.body).scrollTop
).evaluate('> 250');
```

But getting:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work but might not be the best way.

```
describe('scrollTop', function() {
  it('should be greater than 250', function() {
    browser.executeScript('return document.body.scrollTop;').then(function(scrollTop) {
      expect(scrollTop > 250).toBeTruthy()
    });
  });
});
```